# How put over the dot a image, in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

How can i put image in each of objects?

currently only its showing dots, but i need show image

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        var object = objects[i];
        object.y += spawnRateOfDescent;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(object.x, object.y, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2);


       


        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = object.type;
        ctx.fill();
    }
```

I tried with this

```
var img = new Image();
    img.src = "img/HannyahNED/Cohete_1"+".png";
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, object.x, object.y);
    };
```

but does not worked

Comment: do you want to draw images cropped inside circles?

Comment: yes its ok that behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key idea is that loading images is asynchronous. The snippet below loads images first (by creating a promise that resolves when `image.onload` completes).

After that, your code works fine.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

const objects = [{
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    src: "https://via.placeholder.com/60/FF0000" // red image
  },
  {
    x: 90,
    y: 90,
    src: "https://via.placeholder.com/60/00FF00" // green image
  },
  {
    x: 170,
    y: 170,
    src: "https://via.placeholder.com/60/0000FF" // blue image
  }
]

function fetchImage(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = () => resolve(img);
  });
}

const promises = objects.map(object => {
  return fetchImage(object.src).then(img => object.img = img)
});

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  objects.forEach(object => {
    ctx.drawImage(object.img, object.x, object.y);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(object.x, object.y, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  });
})
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```